# how to run a .click on elems parent sibling selector?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, parent, siblings

Below is my most recent attempt:

```
var aSl = document.querySelector('input[id^="blahblah"]');
aSl.closest("span.k-icon.k-i-expand").click();
```

It returned:

*myjs.js:181 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closest' of null*

I have also tried `parent.sibling` in place of `.closest` above - that returned *'...parent is not a function' error.*

Below is my mark-up:

```
<span class="k-icon k-i-expand">::before</span> <--- this is what I'm trying to run .click() on
<span class="k-checkbox-wrapper">
   <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" id="blahblah-blah" class="k-checkbox">
<span>...</span>
</span>
```

Update, I have just tried this as well; per a comment with no avail:

```
var el = document.querySelector('input[id^="blahblah"]');
el.parentNode.parentNode.click();
```

Comment: `closest()` is a jQuery method, not a native method.

Comment: do you want to get  data in the <span>

Comment: `aSl.parentNode.parentNode` should get you the outer span with the `k-icon` class on it

Comment: @taplar it is a native method. Look at [`Element.closest() `](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest).

Comment: I can't find any class with a `k-i-collapse` name in your provided HTML.

Comment: Hah, that's right.  I completely forgot they started implementing that in native.  :S  So weird when native starts implementing library methods, lol

Comment: So if that is the case, then the question becomes what version of the browser is the code being ran in?

Comment: are you sure it's getting the element you want? i mean, if it cannot get a function from null, it normally means your selection is returning nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest() method traverses the Element and **its parents** (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the provided selector string. Will return itself or the matching ancestor. If no such element exists, it returns null.

What you desire to get is actually a **sibling of the parent of aS1**, hence the output is null.

You would have got the desired element if the code was like this.

```
<span class="k-icon k-i-collapse">
   ::before
   <span class="k-checkbox-wrapper">
        <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" id="blahblah-blah" class="k-checkbox">
        <span>...</span>
   </span>
</span>
```

Also note that there was no parent element with class name 'k-i-collapse'.

Comment: Try using sibling selectors +,~ or first find the grandfather element and then simply use class selector. But check whether you have a 'k-i-collapse' class there instead of 'k-i-expand'.

Answer (score -1):

As said on the comment, it seems you are mixing jquery's API with DOM API, stick to one of them and you'll get the result (assuming that the selector for blahblah actually finds an object)