# click on specific sibling after matching text found

Tags: javascript, regex, for-loop, ecmascript-6

I have many of the below '`k-top`' div elements, with the same inner div structure, except different unique text in two places, in 'k-in' and in my checkbox id.

```
<div class="k-top">
<span class="k-icon k-i-expand"></span><-------------- trigger click on this if below text is found
<span class="k-checkbox-wrapper" role="presentation">
<input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" id="unique TEXT99" class="k-checkbox">
<span class="k-checkbox-label checkbox-span"></span>
</span>
<span class="k-in">unique TEXT99</span></div><- if this text is found in k-in trigger click on elem above
```

I want to iterate through all my `span.k-ins` until I find the innerText to match contains of '*unique*' for instance, then once *unique* is found, I want to `.click()`; on it's sibling element '`.k-i-expand`' as seen in the mark-up above. I do not want to trigger a `.click()`; on all `.k-i-expand` just the specific one that has same parent as where my '`unique text`' is found.

Thus far I have tried `.closest`, I have also tried sibling.parent.. both return null or undefined.. Note, I am not using jQuery.

The below works successfully to click all `.k-i-expand` - but I need to .click() only the one where k-in `innerText` contains 'unique'. Ideally I'd use starts with, or contains, but I'd specify the whole word if needed i.e. `unique TEXT99`

```
      let exp = document.querySelectorAll('.k-i-expand'); 
        let i;
        for (i = 0; i < exp.length; ++i) {
            exp[i].click();
        };
```

More previous attempts can be seen here: [how to run a .click on elems parent sibling selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029135/how-to-run-a-click-on-elems-parent-sibling-selector)

Comment: Can you add more HTML to illustrate the structure? Are there multiple k-tops or multiple k-in inside the k-top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a recursive function which checks all it's Siblings until it finds one with the specified innerHTML. If it does not find one, it does nothing:

```
function checkSibling(node) {
  if (node.innerHTML == "unique TEXT99") {
    return true;
  } else if (node.nextSibling) {
    return checkSibling(node.nextSibling);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

async function clickOnNode() {
  let exp = document.querySelectorAll(".k-i-expand");
  for await (const node of exp) {
    const hasText = await checkSibling(node);

    if (hasText) {
      console.log("Result: ", hasText);
      node.click();
    }
  }
}

clickOnNode();
```

I also created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/Gh05d/pen/KKdLGYy?editors=1111) with the code for you to play around. I guess the innerHTML check could be improved via a Regex.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried iterating over the `.k-top` elements and looking into each one to find your `.k-in`?

```
const expandItemsContaining = (text) => {
  // Let's get all the .k-top divs
  const kTops = document.querySelectorAll('.k-top');

  // And peek into each and every one of them
  kTops.forEach(kTop => {
    // First we check whether there is a .k-in containing your text
    const kIn = kTop.querySelector('.k-in');
    const shouldClick = kIn && kIn.innerText && kIn.innerText.indexOf(text) !== -1;

    // And if there is one we find the .k-i-expand and click it
    if (shouldClick) {
      const kExpand = kTop.querySelector('.k-i-expand');
      if (kExpand) {
        kExpand.click();
      }
    }
  })
}
```